# Return next value in Sybase based on condition

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

I have a table like this:

```
date        ticker        price
01/01/17    APPL          700
01/01/17    SNAP          15
01/02/17    APPL          750
01/02/17    SNAP          13
```

I'd want to retrieve the next price for that ticker as an additional column, like so:

```
date        ticker        price      next_price
01/01/17    APPL          700        750
01/01/17    SNAP          15         13
01/02/17    APPL          750        NULL
01/02/17    SNAP          13         NULL
```

I think in most databases you'd be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT date, ticker, price, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ticker 
ORDER BY date ASC) AS RANK 
from table_name
```

and then do something with the rank to find the next_price. Unfortunately Sybase ASE is sadly limited and doesn't support RANK().

Any ideas on what to use instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions:

- each unique `ticker` value has a max of 1 record for any given `date`
- `next_price` is for the next day where 'next' could be defined as +1 day, +2 days, +1 week, +1 month, etc

Off the top of my head ... a bit of a convoluted correlated sub-query to find `next_price` ...

Setup table and data:

```
create table mytab
([date]         date
,ticker         varchar(10)
,price          int
)
go

insert mytab values ('1/1/2017','APPL',700)
insert mytab values ('1/1/2017','SNAP',15)

insert mytab values ('1/2/2017','APPL',750)
insert mytab values ('1/2/2017','SNAP',13)

insert mytab values ('1/5/2017','APPL',800)
insert mytab values ('1/7/2017','SNAP',23)
go
```

One possible query:

```
select  t1.[date],
        t1.ticker,
        t1.price,

        (select price
         from   mytab t2
         where  t2.ticker = t1.ticker
         and    t2.[date] = (-- find the 'next' available day for t1.ticker
                             select  min([date])
                             from    mytab t3
                             where   t3.ticker = t1.ticker
                             and     t3.[date] > t1.[date]
                            )
        ) as next_price

from    mytab t1
order by 1,2
go

 date             ticker     price       next_price
 ---------------- ---------- ----------- -----------
      Jan  1 2017 APPL               700         750
      Jan  1 2017 SNAP                15          13
      Jan  2 2017 APPL               750         800
      Jan  2 2017 SNAP                13          23
      Jan  5 2017 APPL               800        NULL
      Jan  7 2017 SNAP                23        NULL
```

Tested on ASE 15.7 SP138

Comment: This is easy to understand and worked perfectly, even though my data is a little more granular than what I posted. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

You would not use `rank()` for this.  You would use `lead()`.

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select top 1 t2.price
        from table_name t2
        where t2.ticker = t.ticker and t2.date > t.date
        order by t2.date asc
       ) as next_price
from table_name t;
```

If you know the date is the next calendar date, then you could use a `left join` instead -- that would be more efficient.

Comment: And why would a seemingly correct answer be downvoted anonymously?